# Remove transparency from second camera

Tags: unity, camera

I have a scene with two cameras. The goal is to

- display the content of one (little) camera ontop of the content of the other camera (fills the entire screen)

Current problem:

- the content of the little camera has some transparency

I'm not sure how to get rid off the tranparency (I'm somewhat new to Unity). Here is some picture:

[image]

**Context**

- Unity 2021.3.3f1

Comment: It"s not fully clear to me what your desired output is, and how it should differ from what you've shown. Can you edit your post to clarify?

Comment: The small rectangle on the bottom right is slightly green from transparency. I want the transparency to be gone. Anyway I found it. Will post the solution

Comment: So by "remove transparency" you don't mean "cut out transparent pixels" you mean "make opaque"? Including that phrasing might improve search hits on this question and help dispel any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

- the "camera" component has a field "Target Texture".
- Looking for the GameObject with the corresponding texture
- I found that it had a "Raw Image" attached to it with some transparency.
- Removing that transparency solved my problem